# Why do these Haskell functions have these types?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

Can someone explain why these 2 functions have these types? I think I get that the first one should force the return value of g to be the same type like x because of the position of (g y) in the let corresponding to the position of x in the parameters of the function, but it seems that in the second function it does not work like that.

```
f3 g x = let h y = f3 g (g y) in g x  
(t -> t) -> t -> t  
f4 g x = let h y = f4 g (g y) in x  
(t1 -> t) -> t -> t
```

Answer (score 3):

`f3` is a function of two arguments and hence has a type `t2 -> t1 -> t`. Since the result of the function is `g x`, that has type `t`. `g` itself must be a function of one argument, taking an `x` of type `t1`, so `g` has type `t2` = `t1 -> t`. The unused definition of `h y` requires `g` to accept its result type as argument type leading to `t1` = `t`. Together this results in `(t -> t) -> t -> t`.

`f4` is again a function of two arguments and hence has a type `t3 -> t2 -> t`. Since it just returns `x`, `t2` has to equal `t`. The definition of `h y`
constrains `g y` to be of type `t2` aka `t` but places no constraint on the type of `y`, lets call that `t1`. This leads to `t1 -> t` as type of `g`. Substituting the equalities then results in `(t1 -> t) -> t -> t`.

Answer (score 2):

```
f3 g x = let h y = f3 g (g y) in g x
```

Let's look at a simpler version first:

```
f3' g x = g x
```

Here `g` is applied to `x`, and the result of `g` becomes the result of `f3'`. So the type of `f3'` is `(a -> b) -> a -> b`.

The full `f3` contains the subexpression `f3 g (g y)`, which introduces a few additional constraints: `f3 g` is harmless (no additional constraints because `g` is the argument we were called with in the beginning), but (as you said in your question) passing `g y` as the second argument means that the result of `g` must have the same type as `x` (the second parameter).

This means `a = b` and therefore `f3 :: (a -> a) -> a -> a`.

---

In your second example we have

```
f4 g x = let h y = f4 g (g y) in x
```

Without the `let`, it's just:

```
f4' g x = x
```

which has the type `a -> b -> b`.

The full `f4` contains `f4 g (g y)`. For one thing, this means `g` has to be a function (because it's applied to `y`), so our set of constraints looks like this:

```
f4 :: a -> b -> b
g :: a
x :: b
g :: c -> d
a = c -> d
```

Then `(g y)` is used as the second argument to `f4`, which means its type has to be equal to `b`:

```
g y :: b
g :: c -> b
y :: c
d = b
```

`h` isn't used so there are no additional constraints placed on `y` or `f4`. Substituting the variables in the type of `f4`, we get

```
f4 :: (c -> b) -> b -> b
```

(which is equivalent to `(t1 -> t) -> t -> t` modulo naming).